# Wagtail PageChooserBlock custom ordering

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm using PageChooserBlock to display list of objects

```
class ActualSection(models.Model):
    content = StreamField(
        [
            ("article", PageChooserBlock(page_type="articles.Article")),
        ],
        min_num=1,
    )
```

Is there any way to put some custom ordering on it? Because now it's seems like having some random order

Answer (score 0):

StreamField always returns blocks in the order that they were entered. You can manually set the ordering by using the up/down arrows on the edit view.

To order them based on some criterion, you could add a method to the class that applies the ordering, like this:

```py
class ActualSection(models.Model):
    content = StreamField(
        [
            ("article", PageChooserBlock(page_type="articles.Article")),
        ],
        min_num=1,
    )

    def articles_by_title(self):
        articles = [block.value for block in self.content]
        return sorted(articles, key=lambda a: a.title)
```

Comment: Did not help. Ordering stays the same. Maybe some part of the code is missing?

Comment: Have you updated your template to access the `articles_by_title` method rather than `content`?

Comment: Nope. Can you add to your answer how to do this?

Comment: Whatever your code is doing with `my_model.content`, do it with `my_model.articles_by_title` instead. Since you haven't included that part of the code in your question, I can't really give any more detail than that.